# HTML Aligning on the same row

Tags: html, css, alignment

Okay so basically I want my page like this.

(Button) (Number with a border) (Button)

Keep in mind all of this is going to be in another border.

The code is sort of like:

```
    <button>TEST</button> <p>4</p> <button>TEST</button>
```

So how would I make this align correctly? I want it so the number 4 is in the center, then to the right and left are buttons, all on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

CSS (This gives makes a box around the number)

```
span.numborder {
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid #000000;
padding:2px;
}
```

HTML

```
<button>TEST</button> <span class="numborder">4</span> <button>TEST</button>
```

Comment: this should be the most standard solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <button>TEST</button> </td>
        <td> <p>4</p> </td>
        <td> <button>TEST</button> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The HTML to get it done is a bit longer, but it makes it easy to add other elements that you want to be lined up in the same way.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JHgyy/

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block`. Assign this to the elements in which you wish to align

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/x7vpU/

```
button, p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Assign a class to it's container so then all your elements on the page are not aligned according to this rule

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/x7vpU/1/

```
    <div class="buttons-row">
    <button>TEST</button> <p>4</p> <button>TEST</button>
    </div>

    .buttons-row button, .buttons-row p {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

If you use a `span` instead of `<p>` then you will not need any CSS

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/x7vpU/3/

```
<p><button>TEST</button> <span>4</span> <button>TEST</button></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<span><button>TEST</button></span><span> <p>4</p> </span><span><button>TEST</button></span>
```

this will work for sure. because < span> tabs work inline

Comment: <span> tags are inline @Qix

Comment: Explain it in your answer is my point.